# How to get current viewMode property from "Bootstrap Datepicker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How to get current `viewMode` property from "Bootstrap Datepicker"?
I initialize the control with `viewMode= 'years'`  and I want to close datepicker on `changeDate` event, only when `viewMode='days'`.

The user selects a year, then a month, and finally a day. In that moment the control must  be closed.

This is the code:

```
$("#date").datepicker(
    {viewMode: 'years',
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#date').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    //close when viewMode='0' (days)
})
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/nAXnM/

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="02/16/12" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="dp2" >
```

**JS**

```
$("#dp2").datepicker({
 viewMode: 'years',
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#dp2').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
   //close when viewMode='0' (days)
   if(ev.viewMode === 'days'){
      $('#dp2').datepicker('hide');
   }
})
```

Comment: @preveen how is the view mode change in javascript after setup, maybe on select change?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for [the fork of Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [the forked version of Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), to close the UI widget when a date is selected, set the [`autoclose`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#autoclose) option to `true`:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```